# Spectral decomposition of a linear transformation

Tags: linear-algebra, polynomials, linear-transformations, spectral-theory

I have a linear transformation 
[image]

given by [image]

And I need to find its spectral decomposition.

I want to represent T as a matrix so I could find it's eigenvalues , and then calculate their eigenspaces or use Lagrange's interpolation.

I'm not sure if I should represent in base [image]

or in some other base. And if it is in that base, I don't understand how i should look like because of the parameters a,b,c and the given form, because I only saw more simple examples[image] like this:

So I'll be glad to see how is the representative matrix of T looks like and how do I see from it the eigenvalues ?

Comment: Try taking $(a,b,c) = (1,0,0)$ then $(0,1,0)$ and then $(0,0,1)$. This will get it into the form that you like.

Comment: Please include key parts of your question as text, using [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to format mathematical expressions, instead of pasting pictures of them. This question is incomprehensible without those images and so inaccessible to people who depend on screen readers. Moreover, images are neither searchable nor show up in summaries. See [this answer](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question#10992) to “How to ask a good question.”

Comment: As an alternative, you could work directly with polynomials: Write $4ax^2+2bx+2a+3b=\lambda(ax^2+bx+c)$ and compare coefficients.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at $T$ with respect to the basis $\{ x^2, x, 1\}$. Say,
$$
      \left[\begin{array}{c} a \\ b \\ c\end{array}\right]
   \sim ax^2+bx+c.
$$
Then $T(ax^2+bx+c)=4ax^2+2bx+2a+3b$ translates to the following matrix formulation
$$
           \left[ T \right]\left[\begin{array}{c}a \\ b \\ c\end{array}\right] = \left[\begin{array}{c}4a\\2b\\2a+3b\end{array}\right]=\left[\begin{array}{ccc}4 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 2 & 0 \\ 2 & 3 & 0\end{array}\right]\left[\begin{array}{c}a \\ b \\ c\end{array}\right]
$$
The characteristic polynomial of $T$ is
$$
  \det\left[\begin{array}{ccc}\lambda-4 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & \lambda-2 & 0 \\ -2 & -3 & \lambda\end{array}\right] 
  = (\lambda-4)(\lambda-2)\lambda
$$
There is a basis of eigenvectors $\{ 1,2x+3,2x^2+1 \}$ with corresponding eigenvalues $\{0,2,4\}$. That is,
$$
     (T-0I)(1) =0 \\
     (T-2I)(2x+3)=0 \\
     (T-4I)(2x^2+1)=0.
$$